# Create a webscraper with loop to search links

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to create a websraper that will return restaurant names and addresses from the website. In the current version, it returns only names (as a test), but they are saved in the form of a string (`[{'name': 'Copernicus Restaurant | Copernicus Hotel'}] [{'name': 'Copernicus Restaurant | Copernicus Hotel'}, {'name': 'Farina Restaurant'}] [{'name': 'Copernicus Restaurant | Copernicus Hotel'}, {'name': 'Farina Restaurant'}, {'name': 'Cyrano de Bergerac'}]`).

Could someone help me to correct this code so that it would take links to each restaurant and then extract data about the name of the restaurant, address from those links?

I will be grateful for any help.

My code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

driver_service = Service(executable_path="C:/webdrivers/chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=driver_service)
baseurl = 'https://restaurantguru.com/'
driver.get('https://restaurantguru.com/restaurant-Poland-t1')

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
productlist = soup.find_all('div', class_='wrapper_info')

#print(productlist)

productlinks = []
for item in productlist:
    for link in item.find_all('a', href=True):
        productlinks.append(link['href'])

#print(productlinks)

restlist = []

for link in productlinks:
    r = driver.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    name = soup.find('h1', class_='notranslate').text.strip()
    #  address = soup.find('div', class_='address')
    #  try:
    #     website = soup.find('a', href=True)
    #  except:
    #     website = 'NULL'

    rest ={
        'name': name,
        #   'website': website,
        #   'address': address
    }

    restlist.append(rest)
    print(restlist)

driver.quit()
```

Edited code with wrong result:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd
import time
import csv


#driver_service = Service(executable_path="C:/webdrivers/chromedriver.exe")
#driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=driver_service)


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
baseurl = 'https://restaurantguru.com/'
driver.get('https://restaurantguru.com/restaurant-Gostynin-t1')


soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
productlist = soup.find_all('div', class_='wrapper_info')

#print(productlist)

productlinks = []
for item in productlist:
    for link in item.find_all('a', href=True):
        productlinks.append(link['href'])

#print(len(productlinks))


restlist = []

for link in productlinks:
    print('[DEBUG] link:', link)
    driver.get(link)
    print('[DEBUG] soup ...')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    print('[DEBUG] name ...')
    name = soup.find('h1', class_='notranslate').text.strip()
    print(name)
    name = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//h1[@class="notranslate"]').text.strip()
    print(name)
    print('[DEBUG] address ...')
    address = soup.find('div', class_='address').find('div', class_=False).text.strip()
    print(address)
    address = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="address"]/div[2]').text.strip()
    print(address)
    print('[DEBUG] website ...')
    try:
        website = soup.find('div', class_='website').find('a').text #get('href')
        print(website)
        website = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="website"]//a').text #get('href')
        print(website)
    except Exception as ex:
        website = ''
rest = {
    'name': name,
    'website': website,
    'address': address,
}

restlist.append(rest)


print(restlist)
#df = pd.DataFrame(restlist)
#df.to_csv('C:/webdrivers/restauracje.csv')
#print(df.head(10))

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Think the question is missing - Please add some details and a focused question. Thanks

Comment: _restaurant names and addresses_: Can you cite some examples?

Comment: What I want to do is get from this website (https://restaurantguru.com/restaurant-Poland-t1) the name and address of each restaurant, which are provided after clicking on a given restaurant (e.g. in the link https://restaurantguru.com/Copernicus-Krakow)

Comment: selenium has own functions to search in HTML and you don't need `BeautifulSoup`

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see what you get in `driver.page_source`. Maybe server sends different HTML to browser controlled by Selenium. You could also first run without `try/except` to get FULL error message - it can help to see problem. Or maybe it uses JavaScript to add values and `javaScript` needs some time to add it - so you may need `time.sleep`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many `a` with `href` so you have to use more complex method to get `website`.

`website` is in `<div class="website">` so you can do

```
website = soup.find('div', class_='website').find('a').get('href')
```

but real link to restaurant is as text, not href

```
website = soup.find('div', class_='website').find('a').text
```

As for address I also had to add extra `.find('div', class_=False)`
(and `.text.strip()`) to get it

```
address = soup.find('div', class_='address').find('div', class_=False).text.strip()
```

---

Selenium has own methods to search elements in HTML and maybe it would run faster.

```
name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//h1[@class="notranslate"]').text.strip()

address = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="address"]/div[2]').text.strip()

website = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="website"]//a').text #get('href')
```

---

Tested with Firefox on Linux:

In code I keep both methods: `soup.find` and `driver.find_element_by_xpath`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

#driver_service = Service(executable_path="C:/webdrivers/chromedriver.exe")
#driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=driver_service)

try:
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    driver.get('https://restaurantguru.com/restaurant-Poland-t1')

    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    productlist = soup.find_all('div', class_='wrapper_info')

    #print(productlist)

    print('[DEBUG] productlist ...')
    productlinks = []
    for item in productlist:
        for link in item.find_all('a', href=True):
            productlinks.append(link['href'])

    print('len(productlinks):', len(productlinks))

    restlist = []

    for link in productlinks:
        print('[DEBUG] link:', link)
        
        driver.get(link)
        
        print('[DEBUG] soup ...')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

        print('[DEBUG] name ...')
        name = soup.find('h1', class_='notranslate').text.strip()
        print(name)
        name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//h1[@class="notranslate"]').text.strip()
        print(name)

        print('[DEBUG] address ...')
        address = soup.find('div', class_='address').find('div', class_=False).text.strip()
        print(address)
        address = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="address"]/div[2]').text.strip()
        print(address)

        print('[DEBUG] website ...')
        try:
            website = soup.find('div', class_='website').find('a').text #get('href')
            print(website)
            website = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="website"]//a').text #get('href')
            print(website)
        except Exception as ex:
            print('[DEBUG] Exception:', ex)
            website = ''
            print(website)
        
        rest = {
            'name': name,
            'website': website,
            'address': address,
        }

        print('[DEBUG] rest ...')
        print(rest)

        print('-----')

        restlist.append(rest)
        
    # --- after `for`-loop ---

    print(restlist)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("KeyboardInterrupt")
finally:    
    driver.quit()

    # open only once
    with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
        csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=['name', 'website', 'address'])
        csv_writer.writeheader()
        csv_writer.writerows(restlist)
```

Result (from `print(restlist)`)

```
[
{'name': 'Copernicus Restaurant | Copernicus Hotel', 'website': 'https://www.likusrestauracje.pl/', 'address': 'Kanonicza 16, Kraków, Lesser Poland Voivodeship, Poland'}, 
{'name': 'Farina Restaurant', 'website': 'https://www.farina.com.pl/', 'address': 'Świętego Marka 16, Kraków, Lesser Poland Voivodeship, Poland'}, 
{'name': 'Cyrano de Bergerac', 'website': 'http://cyranodebergerac.com.pl', 'address': 'Sławkowska 26, Kraków, Lesser Poland Voivodeship, Poland'}, 
{'name': 'Amarylis Restaurant', 'website': 'https://www.queenhotel.pl/', 'address': 'Józefa Dietla 60, Kraków, Lesser Poland Voivodeship, Poland'}, 
{'name': 'Projekt Nano', 'website': '', 'address': 'Podmurna 17 A, Torun, Kuyavian-Pomeranian Voivodeship, Poland'}, 
{'name': 'Raffles Europejski Warsaw', 'website': 'https://www.raffles.com/warsaw', 'address': 'Nowy Świat-Uniwersytet'}, 
{'name': 'Caffe Horst', 'website': 'http://www.caffehorst.pl/', 'address': 'Świętochłowicka 6, Bytom, Silesian Voivodeship, Poland'}, 
{'name': 'Proza', 'website': '', 'address': 'Jana Karola Chodkiewicza 7, Rzeszow, Podkarpackie Voivodeship, Poland'}, 
{'name': 'Il Posto di Luca Santarossa', 'website': 'http://www.ilposto.pl', 'address': 'Jana Sawy 5/lokal 10, Lublin, Lublin Voivodeship, Poland'}, 
{'name': 'Balkan Bistro Prespa', 'website': '', 'address': 'Władysława Syrokomli 8, Warsaw, Masovian Voivodeship, Poland'}, 
{'name': 'Mr Coffee', 'website': '', 'address': 'Tumska 4, Klodzko, Lower Silesian Voivodeship, Poland'}, 
{'name': 'Bottiglieria 1881 Restaurant', 'website': 'https://www.1881.com.pl/', 'address': 'Bocheńska 5, Kraków, Lesser Poland Voivodeship, Poland'}, 
{'name': 'Albertina Restaurant & Wine', 'website': 'https://www.albertinarestaurant.pl/', 'address': 'Dominikańska 3, Kraków, Lesser Poland Voivodeship, Poland'}, 
{'name': 'Pub & Restauracja „W Sercu Łodzi”', 'website': '', 'address': 'al. Marszałka Józefa Piłsudskiego 138, Łódź, Łódź Voivodeship, Poland'}, 
{'name': '#Alternatywnie', 'website': 'http://www.altcoffee.pl/', 'address': 'aleja Wojska Polskiego 35/u3, Szczecin, West Pomeranian Voivodeship, Poland'}, 
{'name': 'Aqua e Vino', 'website': 'http://www.aquaevino.pl', 'address': 'Wiślna 5/10, Kraków, Lesser Poland Voivodeship, Poland'}, 
{'name': 'Pili Pili Gdańsk', 'website': 'http://www.pilipilicafe.com/', 'address': 'Szafarnia 11/U14, Gdańsk, Pomeranian Voivodeship, Poland'}, 
{'name': 'Kawiarnia Coffeinna', 'website': '', 'address': '1 Maja 26, Jastrzębie-Zdrój, Silesian Voivodeship, Poland'}, 
{'name': 'Mleczarnia', 'website': 'http://www.mle.pl', 'address': 'Rabina, Beera Meiselsa 20, Kraków, Lesser Poland Voivodeship, Poland'}, 
{'name': 'La Squadra Ristorante', 'website': 'http://lasquadra.pl/restauracja/', 'address': 'Bocheńskiego 109, Katowice, Silesian Voivodeship, Poland'}
]
```

Comment: Thank you, the code works almost perfect! The only thing that fails is that only the data of the last restaurant are saved.

Comment: how do you save it ? if you save every resetaurant separatelly using `open(..., "w")` and `close()` then it removes previous data - it has to be in `append mode` - `open(..., "a")`. Or you should open file only once - at start - write every new restaurant when you get it, and close it after last restaurant. OR you should first get all restaurant in list and at tthe end write all data from list at once

Comment: The ```print(restlist)``` (all from your code) gives me only one line about the last restaurant from the list.

Comment: it is strange because I see list with 20 dictionares. maybe you have `restlist = []` in wrong place and you remove previous content. Did you run it with open web browser (with option `headless`) to see if it really get data from other pages?

Comment: I added result from my `print(restlist)`

Comment: in `finally:` I added code to write in file `CSV` using module `csv`

Comment: Part of my result:
```[
[DEBUG] link: https://restaurantguru.com/Przedsiebiorstwo-Rolno-Spozywcze-DUBIELAK-Gostynin
[DEBUG] soup ...
[DEBUG] name ...
Przedsiębiorstwo Rolno - Spożywcze DUBIELAK
Przedsiębiorstwo Rolno - Spożywcze DUBIELAK
[DEBUG] address ...
Płocka 8, Gostynin, Masovian Voivodeship, Poland
Płocka 8, Gostynin, Masovian Voivodeship, Poland
[DEBUG] website ...
https://dubielak.pl/
https://dubielak.pl/
[{'name': 'Przedsiębiorstwo Rolno - Spożywcze DUBIELAK', 'website': 'https://dubielak.pl/', 'address': 'Płocka 8, Gostynin, Masovian Voivodeship, Poland'}]
```

Comment: without full code I can't say what is the problem. At this moment I could say: you have `restlist = []` in wrong place (ie inside `for`-loop) and it removes previous elements.

Comment: and `print(restlist)` should be also outside `for`-loop, and writing in file should be also outside `for`-loop.

Comment: Ok, I added my version of your code to the question.

Comment: you have wrong indentations - `rest = { }` and `restlist.append(rest)` has to be INSIDE `for`-loop. But you have it outside `for`-loop and it is executed only once - after getting last restaurant